# Splitting up a Master DataFrame to mutliple DataFrames in a loop- Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a master data Frame-

```
NHE_17.head()

Out[42]: 
                         Var name     1960     1961     1962     1963  
0  Total National Health Expenditures  27214.0  29138.0  31842.0  34595.0   
1                       Out of pocket  12949.0  13357.0  14255.0  15311.0   
2                    Health Insurance   7497.0   8236.0   8999.0   9892.0   
3            Private Health Insurance   5812.0   6468.0   7178.0   7952.0   
4                            Medicare      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

I am trying to split this data frame into mutliple dataframes based on indices passed in a loop:

```
def slice(idx):
    df_temp= NHE_17.iloc[idx[0]:idx[1]]
    return df_temp

df_list_idx = [['df_1',[0,37]],['df_2',[280,310]]]

for df_name, idx in df_list_idx:
    df = slice(idx)
    df_name= df
```

So ideally, I want 'df_1' to be assigned to NHE_17.iloc[0:37], df_2 to NHE_17.iloc[280:310] and so on...

But that is not happening. df_name retains the dataframe sliced with the last indices passed([280:310] in this case) and doesn't assign to the 'df_name' as it should in the last line within the for loop:

```
df_name= df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a dictionary of DataFrames `dfs`, with keys from the list ('df_1', 'df_2', ...).

Then it's just a loop that populates this dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(500)})

df_list_idx = [['df_1',[0,3]],['df_2',[280,284]]]
dfs = {}
for x in df_list_idx:
    k = x[0] # e.g. 'df_1'
    v = x[1] # e.g. [0,3]
    dfs[k] = df.iloc[v[0]:v[1]]

print(dfs['df_1'])
print(dfs['df_2'])
```

Output:

```
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
       a
280  280
281  281
282  282
283  283
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to pandas, or dataframes, but a basic programming issue. You're trying to assign a variable to a string. That is:

```
'a' = 2 # example
'df_1' = df # what you are trying to do in essence.
```

Python, or any language that I know if will not let you do this, because a string (e.g. `'df_1'`) is not a valid variable name.

Instead, I think the best way to do this is by adding the slices to a list.

```
df_list_idx = [[0,37],[280,310]]
data = []
for idx in df_list_idx:
    df = slice(idx)
    data.append(df)
```

Now you could index within the `data` variable. If instead you have many more indecisive, you would probably not want to create many more variables anyway.

```
df_1 = data[0]
df_2 = data[1]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. That makes sense! I wasn't able to find a way to add dataframes within a list without passing it in quotes.